# Rails Dynamic Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, dynamic

How can I dynamically configure a validation in rails? 
For EXAMPLE if I have

```
validates_length_of :name, within => dynamic
```

The variable "dynamic" will be set by the user. On save, the validation should use the value of the variable "dynamic" to configure the within configuration.

Comment: You should take a look on [defining dynamic validations with procs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9961015/1287376).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe `validates_length_of` supports dynamic parameters. You'll need to duplicate the behavior in a custom validation.

```
# in model
def validate
  unless (5..10).member? name.length
    errors.add :name, "must be within 5 to 10 characters"
  end
end
```

That uses a static range, but you can easily use your own custom range variable.

```
def validate
  unless some_range.member? name.length
    errors.add :name, "must be within #{some_range.first} to #{some_range.last} characters"
  end
end
```

You may want to check out my [Railscasts episode on conditional validations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations) and Episode 3 in my [Everyday Active Record series](http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-rbar/everyday-active-record).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the dynamic variable on validates_presence_of like this: validates_presence_of :name, :locales => dynamic_array (:locales can be [:en, :de,...] dynamic). The configuration :locales by validates_presence_of comes with the i18n_multi_locales_validations plugin.