# Cannot call association methods from validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble calling the methods generated by by my associations in my validations.

My code is pretty simple:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :tournament

  has_many :match_player_relations
  has_many :waiting_players, through: :match_player_relations
  has_many :replays

  # Validations
  validates :tournament_id, presence: true
  validates :winner_id, inclusion: { in: waiting_players.map { |wp| wp.id } }
end
```

I have verified in my tests that there is a waiting_players method, and it works correctly. However, when I try to call it in my validations I get the following error:

```
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `waiting_players' for #<Class:0x007fc3b498c9c8> (NameError)
    from /Users/max/workplace/CloudLeagues/app/models/match.rb:11:in `<class:Match>'
```

Is there a way to solve this? Or do I need to remove the validation?

Comment: Does it work with `self.waiting_players` ?

Comment: It may not be possible, looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034988/rails-3-validates-inclusion-of-when-using-a-find-how-to-proc-or-lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to pass a lambda to `in` to access the current record:

```
validates :winner_id, inclusion: { 
  in: lambda {|match| match.waiting_players.map { |wp| wp.id }}
}
```

Comment: This is almost the correct answer. This does verify that winner_id is a waiting player. However, it has the caveat that the validation fails if winner_id is not present. Simply adding `presence: false` does not fix this. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. All I needed to do was add if: :winner_id after the inclusion hash.